# What are some simple and fast data visualization-tools?

Tags: data-visualization

I'm buying an apartment. Being me I started by scarping all sales prices from the last 2 years.

Now I'm looking for a tool to quickly play around with and get a feel for the data. Its about 90000 lines so it has to be able to do some heavy lifting, I want to be able to do stuff like, price/square meter over time, grouped by streetname. I keep the data in a csv right now but can shuffle it around and also massage the data programatically.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what your requirements are (programming language, static images, interaction, …). For Python, there's a recent overview on the [Anaconda blog](https://www.anaconda.com/python-data-visualization-2018-why-so-many-libraries/) or http://pyviz.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that Public Tableau is a free solution for you because u can go with programming and non-programming background.
Also in python you can use Matplotlib that is really easy to use.
In R you can go for ggplot that is quite easy to satisfy your needs.
Matlab is also another handy solution.
I believe you can search youtube for some videos that can give you some insight the above tools.